# Cross mark on a visa stamp - Bahamas

Tags: visas, passport-stamps, bahamas

I've applied for a Bahamas visit visa from India and I just got my passport today. I see two stamps in my passport - one Bahamas 3 months visit visa stamp and another stamp (same visa) with a cross mark on it.

Is it just because it wasn't stamped properly? Is this going to create any issue during immigration?

[image]

Comment: Did you apply directly yourself or use an agency? Have you contacted the Bahamas consulate that issued the visa? I wouldn’t want to rely solely on opinions from the internet if I were in this situation.

Comment: I took the help of a consultant to fill up my application form and I submitted my VISA through VFS UK. I was granted the visa by UK on behalf of Bahamas. I'm not sure if calling the UK international customer support is going to help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

That stamp has been crossed out for being illegible. If they wanted to indicate that your visa had been cancelled they should not have left another stamp intact. This should not cause any problems.